# Why specify the same volume for two services?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

This is more of a why? question. I have the below `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - app-network

  php:
    image: php:8.3-fpm
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:11.3
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
      MYSQL_USER: myuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata: {}
```

Separately I have the following nginx file (default.conf in the above).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

My question is for the `volumes:` for `php` and `nginx` on `docker-compose.yml`. I wanted to know why I would specify the same volume for two containers and not just nginx? I was under the impression that any file that is loaded by nginx is passed through the php container via the `fastcgi_pass` address location. Therefore only nginx needs to have the volume mounted.

Comment: Without seeing the PHP code, we can't know. But since only `.php` requests are passed to the php container, one reason might be file uploads. If a file is uploaded via a `.php` page, the file is written by the PHP container. By using a shared volume, NGINX can then serve the file after it's been uploaded.

Comment: @HansKilian the above applies to any php file. If you made a file with `phpinfo();` inside and placed it into the volume path for `nginx`, but didn't specify it for `php`, it would say file not found. As an example, I have put `phpinfo.php` into the volume for nginx service, but not php, it says file not found. If the file exists on the `php` service, but not `nginx`, then it loads. I am confused how this works because as it is nginx should see the file doesn't exist and throw a 404, but the file exists, but php doesn't load it.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens if you omit one of them?

Comment: @NicoHaase As previously mentioned, I have it working. The question is why does the volume need to be shared with the same paths for php + nginx rather than just nginx.
This isn't a question that needs a working solution, I am trying to understand why both docker containers need the same volume and why is it not nginx.

Comment: My point is if your PHP container creates a file called `/var/www/html/myimage.jpg`, there's no way to retrieve it without the volume sharing. The volume sharing lets Nginx return the file on  a GET request for `/myimage.jpg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your project looks like this:

```
├── app
│   ├── index.php
│   └── static.html
├── default.conf
└── docker-compose.yml
```

In `app/` there is both a PHP source file and a static HTML file.

This is a simplified `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php

  php:
    image: php:8.3-fpm
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
```

The `app/` directory needs to be volume mounted on both services.

The `php` service is there to transform the `.php` files into HTML. So the `.php` files need to be available to this service. If there is no volume mount here then PHP-FPM has nothing to process.

PHP-FPM does not process static files, so static files need to be volume mounted on the `nginx` service directly as well. You can remove the PHP-FPM service and the static file will still work fine.